# Magento 2 custom API not working. Class not found

Tags: magento2, error, api

I have a problem with creating my custom api.
I've created directory `app/code/Openc/GCApi`
with the following files:

> 1. app/code/Openc/GCApi/etc/module.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"              
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
         <module name="Openc_GCApi" setup_version="1.0.0" />
    </config>
```

> 2. app/code/Openc/GCApi/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
       \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
       'Openc_GCApi',
       __DIR__
);
```

> 3. app/code/Openc/GCApi/etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../app/code/Magento/Webapi/etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/gcapiapi/:name" method="GET">
        <service class="Openc\GCApiApi\Api\GcapiapiInterface" method="name" />
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
```

> 4. app/code/Openc/GCApi/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Openc\GCApiApi\Api\GcapiapiInterface" type="Openc\GCApiApi\Model\Gcapiapi"/>
</config>
```

> 5. app/code/Openc/GCApi/Api/GcapiapiInterface.php

```
    <?php
    namespace Openc\GCApi\Api;
    interface GcapiapiInterface
    {
        /**
        * Returns greeting message to user
        *
        * @api
        * @return string Greeting message with users name.
        */
        public function name(string $name);
     }
```

> 6. app/code/Openc/GCApi/Model/Gcapiapi.php

```
     <?php
     namespace Openc\GCApiApi\Model;
     use Openc\GCApi\Api\GcapiapiInterface;
     class Gcapiapi implements GcapiapiInterface
     {
        /**
        * Returns greeting message to user
        *
        * @api
        * @param string $name Users name.
        * @return string Greeting message with users name.
        */
        public function name(string $name) {
            return "Hello ".$name;
        }
     }
```

Here is the file for testing my custom API:

```
    <?php
    define('BASEURL','[base url]');
    $apiUser = 'apicustomer'; 
    $apiPass = 'admin123';
    $apiUrl = BASEURL.'index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';

    $data = array("username" => $apiUser, "password" => $apiPass);                                                                    

    $data_string = json_encode($data);                       
    try{
       $ch = curl_init($apiUrl); 
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          

           'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                

           'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       

       );       
       $token = curl_exec($ch);
       $token = json_decode($token);
       if(isset($token->message)){
            echo $token->message;
       }else{
            $key = $token;
       }
    }catch(Exception $e){
       echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
    }


    $headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $key"); 
    $requestUrl = BASEURL.'index.php/rest/V1/gcapiapi/testname';

    $ch = curl_init();
    try{
       $ch = curl_init($requestUrl); 
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   

       $result = curl_exec($ch);
       $result = json_decode($result);

       if(isset($result->message)){
           echo $result->message;
       }else{
           print_r($result);
       }
       }catch(Exception $e){
           echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage(); 
       }
```

And here is the error which I'm getting:

Class `Openc\GCApiApi\Api\GcapiapiInterface` does not exist.

Comment: @ Alex, Have you resolved the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some places where your namespaces are mismatched. You're using `GCApiApi` in your namespace/xml, instead of `GCApi`. I assume that's not intentional? Try correcting this.

Comment: Yea, Joe is right.

Comment: @ Alex, Open your file app/code/Openc/GCApi/Model/Gcapiapi.php  and update the line, namespace Openc\GCApiApi\Model;   to namespace Openc\GCApi\Model;